# An entire function satisfying $f(z)=f(z+\xi t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and some $\xi\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f$ be entire function satisfying $f(z)=f(z+\xi t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, some $\xi\in\mathbb{C}\neq 0$ and all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. I would like to show that $f$ is constant.

Since $f(z+\xi t)-f(z)=0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, we have that by the holomorphicity of $z$,
$$0=\xi\lim_{t\xi \to 0}\frac{f(z+\xi t)-f(z)}{\xi t}=\xi f'(z)$$
Thus, we must have $f'(z)=0$ everywhere and $f$ is constant.

Is the proof correct and is there another proof of this result?

Comment: If that equation $f(z) = f(z + \xi t)$ is actually true for all $z$ and not just for one, then your argument works and is probably the simplest way to show it.  I have some minor quibbles with precisely how you've written some points, but the idea is clear when taken together.  If you know some theorems of complex analysis, you might also prove the same theorem when the equation is only true for a particular $z = z_0$.

Comment: Letting $t$ be ${1 \over n}$ we get $z_n \to z$ with $f(z_n) = f(z)$ hence $f(w)=f(z)$ everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is fine. Even less would have made $f$ constant. For example, the condition is not needed for all $z$, just one $z_0$ would be enough. This is because the function $g(z)=f(z_0+z)-f(z_0)$ is zero on a set, all $\xi t$, that accumulates inside where $g$ is analytic. Therefore $g(z)$ is identically zero.

Comment: @geetha290krm Clear typo. the $-f(z)$ should be $-f(z_0)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm It is an obvious typo.

Comment: +1. Good answer.